# Calling C# method using external program (ie: Iron Python)

Tags: c#, python, scripting, ironpython

I've been working on using external programs to script for a C# project, and being somewhat of a programming noob, I've hit a roadblock.

So far I've been able call a python script using a button click in the C# project. I implemented this by doing

**myproject_ironpython.cs**

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

private static void doPython()
{
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    engine.ExecuteFile(@"Hello_World.py"); //Outputs "Hello World" on cmd prompt in C#
}
```

I've also been able to call a function that is part of the C# project while the application is running (the most basic form of scripting, if you will). I do this by implementing a command line that accepts a string, which is then interpreted.

**myproject_invoke.cs**

```
using System.Reflection;

private void buttonExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Cmd = tbCmdLine.Text;

    // Copy line from tbCmdLine to tbPrevious
    tbCmdLine.Clear();
    tbPrevious.AppendText(Cmd);
    tbPrevious.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

    // Process string before passing to invoker
    string[] CmdSegments = Cmd.Split('(', ')');
    Cmd = CmdSegments[0];
    string[] parameters = CmdSegments[1].Split(',');

    // pass string and type to invoker
    this.Invoke(this.GetType().ToString(), Cmd, parameters);
}
```

I can then call various functions by inputting a string.

**My vision** was to use a language besides C# that is good at data processing (Python, MatLab, Igor, etc.). I inherited the C# application (which is good at *taking* data), so I wanted to make certain methods externally callable (ie: take2Ddata()). This would allow me to write a full on script in some other language while using this application.

**How do I take that final step** of sending a string of text to C# from a different programming language? Maybe I'm not thinking about this the right way, and one of you has a recommendation for a different approach.

Thanks!

Comment: why not tagged `IronPython`

Comment: Quite a broad question. IronPython and Matlab both understand .Net and can load and make full use of a .Net Assembly (.Net code compiled into a DLL) via [clr.AddReference](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html) / NET.addAssembly respectively.  Alternatively compiling a .Net Assembly to be COM visible allows the .Net code to be consumed by any language that understands COM.